# SQL efficiently select values where that value has a record in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, where-in

There is a table `users` with fields `fbid` and `fcmtoken`. Then there is a table `friends` with fields `fbid` and `friendfbid`. So in `friends` table, to get all of my friends, it would have to be done like this(just to help you get the idea):

```
SELECT friendfbid FROM friends WHERE fbid = MYFBID
```

I need to make a query to get all fcmtokens of my friends. I made it like this and it seems to work:

```
SELECT
    fbid,
    fcmtoken
FROM
    users
WHERE
    EXISTS (
        SELECT
            friendfbid
        FROM
            friends
        WHERE
            fbid = ?
        AND friendfbid = users.fbid
    )
```

Is it efficient enough? It seems to create a lot of select queries, so that makes me think about it.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath give me an example with it, I rarely make SQL queries, so don't know much about it. I made this query basically just to show "what have I tried"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving the `WHERE fbid = ?` into the outer query:

```
SELECT
    fbid,
    fcmtoken
FROM
    users
WHERE fbid = ?
AND EXISTS (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            friends
        WHERE
            friendfbid = users.fbid
    )
```

But a join might be more efficient:

```
SELECT
    u.fbid,
    u.fcmtoken
FROM users AS u
JOIN friends AS f
  ON f.friendfbid = u.fbid
WHERE f.friendfbid = ?
```

Comment: Thanks, changed `WHERE f.friendfbid = ?`to `WHERE f.fbid = ?`, works, you da real mvp

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.friendfbid, b.fcmtoken from friends a, users b where a.fbid = b.fbid
```